# Excel: Index/Match with Conditional Rank or If Statement within

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a situation where I have built a formula for INDEX/MATCH, but want to basically say "if shapes exists, choose the program one (column I). Otherwise it's ok to use a non-program."

Currently, it will pick whichever criteria comes first, which makes sense. However, if there is, let's say, a program that exists, I want it to choose that row. The example below returns F3 and G3 as "triangle" and "star", respectfully. It **should** return "star" and "square" per the program existing.

Table 1, columns A-E are user input. Columns F and G are automated with the formula seen below.

Table 2, all columns are locked parameters to index and match. If nothing matches, it should show "No Shape Exists".

`=IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:$M$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($J$2:$J$4=$A2)*($K$2:$K$4=$B2)*($L$2:$L$4=$C2)*($O$2:$O$4<=$D2)*($P$2:$P$4>=$D2)*($Q$2:$Q$4<=$E2)*($R$2:$R$4>=$E2),),0)),"No Shape Exists")`

[image: Here is my criteria. F and G columns auto-populate based on the formula.]

[image: Here is the list to index/match from]

edits: clarified that if no program exists then it's ok to use a non-program. Fixed typo in my formula.

Comment: Look at throwing in ($I$2:$I$4="Program") into that formula construction somewhere?

Comment: If I do that, it will **only** look at that. I want it to prioritize the "program", but if there isn't a "program" then use whatever it can find.

Comment: have a look at the answer I gave. It deals with the case as a conditional on program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing I can come up with is this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:$M$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($I$2:$I$4="Program")*($J$2:$J$4=$A2)*($K$2:$K$4=$B2)*($L$2:$L$4=$C2)*($O$2:$O$4<=$D2)*($P$2:$P$4>=$D2)*($Q$2:$Q$4<=$E2)*($R$2:$R$4>=$E2),),0)),IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:$M$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($J$2:$J$4=$A2)*($K$2:$K$4=$B2)*($L$2:$L$4=$C2)*($O$2:$O$4<=$D2)*($P$2:$P$4>=$D2)*($Q$2:$Q$4<=$E2)*($R$2:$R$4>=$E2),),0)),"No Shape Exists"))
```

all in one view:

=IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:$M$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($I$2:$I$4="Program")*($J$2:$J$4=$A2)*($K$2:$K$4=$B2)*($L$2:$L$4=$C2)*($O$2:$O$4<=$D2)*($P$2:$P$4>=$D2)*($Q$2:$Q$4<=$E2)*($R$2:$R$4>=$E2),),0)),IFERROR(INDEX($M$2:$M$4,MATCH(1,INDEX(($J$2:$J$4=$A2)*($K$2:$K$4=$B2)*($L$2:$L$4=$C2)*($O$2:$O$4<=$D2)*($P$2:$P$4>=$D2)*($Q$2:$Q$4<=$E2)*($R$2:$R$4>=$E2),),0)),"No Shape Exists"))

Comment: What I do not like about this is having to maintain the equation twice now. Please let me know if anyone has a better way

Answer (score 0):

this should do it for you:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(M:M, MODE.MULT(IF(
($J$2:$J$4=$A2)*($K$2:$K$4=$B2)*($L$2:$L$4=$C2)*($O$2:$O$4<=$D2)*($P$2:$P$4>=$D2)*($Q$2:$Q$4<=$E2)*($R$2:$R$4>=$E2)
* IF($I$2:$I$4="Program", {1,1,1}, {1,1,0}), ROW($M$2:$M$4), FALSE))), "No shape exists")`

For easy maintainability, I's use Alt-Enter in the formula bar and keep your main conditional in the middle like in the image. Then you can see treat that as necessary and keep the rest around it.

It takes your 1/0 s and then repeats the "program" lines by more than it does the non-program lines. 
Then uses MODE.MULT to use the most occurring row index. If there is no program, it will just use the first qualifying non-program index.

Any questions, please ask...

[image]

Comment: Did this help you?